# How to assign privileges to employees by using checkbox selections in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a web application in asp.net c#.

The project is for assigning tasks to different employees in the system. The project requires that, there are three types of employees, and the privileges corresponding to them are basic, superviser and manager.

The "basic" privilege only has the option to view his/her profile. The "superviser" can create jobs, and when "manager" approves the job, it would become available, and the "superviser" can assign the job to an employee.

As said above, aach of the privileges have a set of avaiable "Actions". My requirement is the following:-

After an employee is created by the admin, the employee need to be given the privileges. The admin can select the privileges (say for example, for basic employee-->view profile, view the work assigned; for superviser--> view profile, create jobs, assign employee to jobs; for manager--> view profile, create job, approve job, assign work to employee; for admin--> all privileges). The admin should be able to "check" the checkboxes associated with each privilegs, and based on these selections, privileges should be assigned to each employee.

How do we do this.

NB:- I dont want to use the "Roles" feature in ASP.NET C#. This is because, only privileges created by the programmer can be used. I want the admin to create roles, by giving a role name, and selecting various privileges.

I have had a look at the features of default asp.net roles and privileges, but my requirement is on the other side of the court.

**The project has different users, and I don't want to categorize them as either "basic emp", "hr", "pm", etc. Instead I would prefer to have a seto of checkboxes, and select the required privileges by using the check boxes.

An employee who has been given the privileges by selection of checkboxes can access the corresponding pages.

For example:

I have a set of checkboxes having associated data as:-

-view profile

-edit profile

-create project

-edit project

-upload resume

If I select the checkboxes corresponding to them, the corresponding web pages will be accessible to them.

How is this possible?**

Comment: You'll have to create a custom implementation. E.g., create your own role base control tables

Comment: Can you please give a bit more of details?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own security system. In case of asp.net webform . Create a lookup table containing all the pages name that appears in the question have mention something like this

```
           Name           Id   Page
           Edit Profile   1    editProfile.aspx
           Update Resume  2    UpdateResume.aspx
```

Now maintain the relation ship of user and associated pages like this in use table

```
           User Id AllowedPageid
             1         1 
             2         1
             2         2
```

Now create a security class which can take the URL of the page and have a method to return true and false

```
          bool IsAllowed(int UserId , string pageURL)
          {
                 // Get the page name and check the DB of User is allowed to access the page
          }
```

Make sure you call this method in every Page_Load method to check if it return false redirect to NoAuthorization page

Comment: Thank you for the response.
Is it like the following?

That is, create a table with two columns, one for id, and the other for a corresponding page. Then, create another table "allowed_pages" where each of the selected chockboxes be marked against the page ids?

Comment: @user2625672 is that table will also store the user role or user id what ever you want and then it will checked against the role id or user id with the page allowed. The reason to put the check on page load because it will called all the time.

Comment: Hello @devesh, I understood it now. There is one more thing I wish to ask. Since, each users have access to different pages, and some people doesn't have access to certain pages, how is it possible to populate menu items for each users, as each users will have different emnu items ?

Comment: @user2625672 One idea you can follow , that I have done . Have a dynamic menu. Create a menu control , once the user is authorized , get all the allowed pages and construct the menu. As it can be come slow , use the cache to store the menu because it can not change very frequently